# Matching and lookup in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

My question is

```
Column A :Customer code from database,

Column B :Customer name from database,

Column C :Customer name from Source B,

Column D :Customer name from Source C,

Column E :Outcome(Customer code after matching C&D with B)
```

Expected outcome

1. Matching Column C and Column D with Column B, and find up Column A at Column E.
2. If column C & D does not match column B, show the closest answer

I had tried with Index, matching but still confused on the outcome and defintely it is not what i'm looking for. I had tried this formula but not what is expected. =INDEX(A2:A1000,MATCH(C2,B1:B1000,0))

Comment: Can you give a data example and explain how column C and D match column B? How can values from two columns match a value in one column? As a new user, please read this carefully: Edit your question to provide the requested clarification. Do not do that in a comment. Post a comment when you have edited the question, so the people following this question get notified,

Comment: Please elaborate on your definition of `closest answer`. In the following three examples which two are the closest match: `ColB - Jimmy Wong`, `ColC - Jimmy W`, `ColD - Jim Wong`? It can be a very complicated process of finding the **closest match**.